# How split UI code from razor page to class with blazor server

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I get 2 errors with the code below

- The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'OnSubmit' does not exist in the current context

The .cs code in the razor page in `@code {}` works

I tried with `public partial class SearchRequest: ComponentBase` but still the errors.

I use .NET 6

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

In Search.razor :

```
@page "/search"
@using Models

<RadzenTemplateForm TItem="SearchRequestModel" Data=@model Submit=@OnSubmit>
    <div class="row px-3">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 p-3">
            <RadzenCard>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 align-items-center d-flex">
                        <RadzenLabel Text="Cardholder" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <RadzenTextBox style="width: 100%;" Name="CardHolder" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </RadzenCard>
        </div>
    </div>
</RadzenTemplateForm>
```

In Search.cs :

```
namespace MyApp.Pages
{
    public partial class SearchRequest
    {
        public SearchModel model { get; set; } = new SearchModel();

        void OnSubmit(SearchModel searchModel)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of your partial class is supposed to match the name of the file of your razor page:

`public partial class Search`

It's a partial class for a razor page so you should name it `Search.razor.cs`.

Here is the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#partial-class-support).

Comment: There is the 'Request.razor' and now I renamed the partial file 'Request.Razor.cs', the class name is 'Request' but I still have these errors.

Comment: Did you check the namespaces ? They are supposed to match too.

Comment: The .razor file there is no namespace, the partial class named Search.razor.cs is in the same namespace

Comment: The namespace of the razor component by default depends on where the file is located in the file system. Here it should be in the `Pages` folder for the namespaces to match.[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#namespaces)

Answer (score -1):

The razor file is named like this :
That's work for me

Search.razor

```
// The file name can be Search.cs or Search.razor.cs both work
public partial class SearchBase : ComponentBase
{
}
```

In the razor page add this :

```
@inherits SearchBase
```

Comment: If you use inheritance there is not point for the class to be `partial`. There are two ways to do code-behind in Blazor: using inheritance or using partials. What @T.Trassoudaine answered is the partial approach which is usually preferred.

Comment: I prefer partial but does not work with  @T.Trassoudaine solution.

Comment: Try delete both files and create again in the same folder so that their namespaces match. They should be in the same folder and have matching names `Search.razor` `Search.razor.cs` and the partial class should also be named `Search`.

Comment: I already tried.